# SQlite DB search where

Tags: android, sqlite

How do I search the database by the name written in EditText?

My code:

```
SQLiteDatabase vt = VtArac.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor VTYeri = vt.query(DatabaseHelper.VT_TABLO, new String[]{ "Id", "banka", "sira", "kod", "aktif", "rea", "kap", "Ryzde", "Kyzde"}, "Id" + "=" + "1", null, null, null,null, null);
startManagingCursor(VTYeri);
while(VTYeri.moveToNext()) {
    String Id_Degiskeni = VTYeri.getString((VTYeri.getColumnIndex("Id")));
    IDDD.setText(Id_Degiskeni.toString());
    String banka_Degiskeni = VTYeri.getString((VTYeri.getColumnIndex("banka")));
    editText1.setText(banka_Degiskeni.toString());
    String sira_Degiskeni = VTYeri.getString((VTYeri.getColumnIndex("sira")));
    editText2.setText(sira_Degiskeni.toString());
    String kod_Degiskeni = VTYeri.getString((VTYeri.getColumnIndex("kod")));
    editText3.setText(kod_Degiskeni.toString());
    String aktif_Degiskeni = VTYeri.getString((VTYeri.getColumnIndex("aktif")));
    aktif.setText(aktif_Degiskeni.toString());
    String rea_Degiskeni = VTYeri.getString((VTYeri.getColumnIndex("rea")));
    reaktif.setText(rea_Degiskeni.toString());
    String kap_Degiskeni = VTYeri.getString((VTYeri.getColumnIndex("kap")));
    kapasitif.setText(kap_Degiskeni.toString());
    String Ryzde_Degiskeni = VTYeri.getString((VTYeri.getColumnIndex("Ryzde")));
    Ryuzde.setText(Ryzde_Degiskeni.toString());
    String Kyzde_Degiskeni = VTYeri.getString((VTYeri.getColumnIndex("Kyzde")));
    Kyuzde.setText(Kyzde_Degiskeni.toString());
}
```

Comment: please post your question in English. Edit it as well.

Comment: Please write you question in english otherwise you can use GoogleTranslate here https://translate.google.co.in/?hl=en&tab=wT

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @jbihan Don't remove pertinent text from questions. It wasn't in English, but it's not hard to use Google translate.

Comment: @Esoteric Screen Name, yes I just realized I had done that mistake when I saw the first comment, I just submitted a new edit to rewrite it. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

The current query is "Id = 1". You want to query based on text from an EditText. Is this right?

If I am right:
The [reference documentation for SQLiteDatabase.query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is a guide:

Instead of entering 
`"Id" + "=" + "1"`
add this:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(<resId>);
String enteredText = mEditText.getText().toString();
String[] args = new String[1];
args[0] = enteredText;
```

For the query, use

```
Cursor VTYeri = vt.query(DatabaseHelper.VT_TABLO, new String[]{ "Id", "banka", "sira", "kod", "aktif", "rea", "kap", "Ryzde", "Kyzde"}, "Id" + " = ?", args, null, null,null, null);
```

This will bind the value of enteredText to your selection statement "Id = ". Argument binding is the only secure way to do queries; concatenation leaves you open to SQL injection, which can be very dangerous. Even so, you should add to my code by doing your own input validation.